# Readlines of blob in Azure Storage Really Slow

Tags: c#, azure-storage

Im using CloudBlockBlob and OpenReadAsync to open a file in azure storage and using readline looping through the file to process the lines.

However this is really slow and takes forever to go through a 3gb file with approx. 70million lines in it.

Whats the best practice with something like this? Download to a temp directory first? but I don't know if that will make the read any faster?

Comment: Can you quantify *really slow*? You are downloading 3gb after all...

Comment: Well the download and upload speed between storage and app service is really fast as you would expect in the same data centre. Takes about 2 mins to download it but after 10 minutes the readline is only 10 million lines in so to read all 70 million lines would take over an hour based on that.

Comment: Im just wondering if downloading the file first and then reading lines is faster than opening the file as a stream

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downloading contents of a Azure blob as a text string taking too long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983587/downloading-contents-of-a-azure-blob-as-a-text-string-taking-too-long-time) also i would suggest you to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128977/storageexception-when-downloading-a-large-file-over-a-slow-network

Answer (score 0):

As reference, I have an idea about readlines a block blob parallelly in stream.

According to the offical document about [`Azure Blob storage limits`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#azure-blob-storage-limits), the max size of a block in a block blob is 100 MB, so there is 31 blocks at least in a 3GB file of block blob.

[image]

Assume that each line in the file was generated automatically by a service to write into a blob, so I think there are a lot of completed lines without break in a block.

Therefore, the solution to readlines parallel with multi-threads or multi-processes is using [`Get Block List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-block-list) in main thread and [`Get Blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob) in Range (for REST API, to set `Range` or `x-ms-range` in request header, as below) in each work thead.

[image]

Here is the steps of the logic flow above.

1. In main thread, to get the block list of a block blob, the block list response body includes the id and size of echo block, as below.

   [image]

   So you can easily compute the range of each block, for example above, the first and second blocks' range are `0-4194304` and `4194305-8388608`.
2. To create a thread pool, you can specify a work thread to process one block, then to reduce the time cost of all lines of the whole blob processing for accelerating. However, it is still up to your network bandwidth if the program run locally. Considering for the order of results of all threads, just need to combine each result with its block id to follow the block list order.

A more complex case, if the 3GB file is uploaded to Blob Storage, the first and last line in a block may be broke. So except the first block of a blob, you have to deal with this case to concat the break line in two adjacent blocks via judge whether be exists a `\n` character at the end of a block.

Hope it helps.