# MemoryStream is not expandable for fixed buffer size

Tags: c#, .net, buffer, memorystream

Firstly I'm not that experienced with streams but I'm trying to read this csv file stored at my storage account -> container. I'm retrieving this file successfully throught a `BlobClient`. However some of the csv files are 600mbs so it takes a while to `blob.DownloadTo()` them. What I'm trying to achieve is to fix the size of the buffer to 4mb and always get only the first 4mbs of the csv file. For that purpose, I have this code:

```cs
private void getCsv(BlobClient blob)
{
    string text;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    {
        blob.DownloadTo(memoryStream);
        text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

This code breaks with the error `memory stream can not be expendable`. Any ideas where I'm doing wrong or something? If this code doesn't do, by any case, what I'm trying to achieve, how can I achieve it (ideas)?

Comment: Looks like the most sensible thing to do is to get a stream using `blog.OpenRead`, and then read the first 4mb of that (e.g. using `stream.Read` to read it directly into an array of the right size)

Comment: However, I see that you are reading that truncated stream as UTF-8. This is not safe. UTF-8 code points can span multiple bytes, which means it's possible that your 4mb hard stop is in the middle of a code point, meaning the last character will be corrupted. Not good. Maybe you actually want to download the first 4096 *characters* (subtle difference)? If so, it's probably easiest to do `new StreamReader(blob.OpenRead())`, then one of the `Read` or `ReadBlock` overloads which takes a limit of the number of characters to read? If you can't do this, mess around with `Encoding.GetDecoder()`

Comment: This should help - you can just exit after downloading first 4MB - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31129288/4800344

Comment: E.g. `using (var sr = new StreamReader(blob.OpenRead())) { var str = string.Create(4096, sr, (span, sr) => sr.ReadBlock(span)); }`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using

```cs
private void getCsv(BlobClient blob) 
{
    using(var sr = new StreamReader(blob.OpenRead())) 
    {
        var str = string.Create(4096, sr, (span, sr) => sr.ReadBlock(span));
    }
}
```

This is a working solution that reads the first 4096 characters of the file, provided by @canton7. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Actually, note that if you download less than 4096 characters, your string could end up with garbage in it. You probably want to add `(span, sr) => { span.Clear(); sr.ReadBlock(span); }`